# JavaScript doesn't see a variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(function ($) {
...
});

var getNotifyBar = $(".NotifyBar");
function showNotify(text) {
    getNotifyBar.hide().find(".text").html(text).end().slideDown();
}
```

And when I use function `showNotify(text)` nothing happens. But when I put it in the JavaScript console (of the browser) it works.

Comment: What does the random anonymous function at the top have to do with anything??? Just an FYI: You're accepting a parameter in your anonymous function but you're not passing it in. (i.e. `$(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);`)

Comment: How or where is the `text` var defined that is passed into showNotify?

Comment: Try `$(".NotifyBar").hide().etc...` - your `getNotifyBar` variable is probably an empty jQuery object because it is created before the DOM is ready (assuming that script is in the `<head>` or before the element in question).

Comment: @mrk If you mean inside the function, that's the argument

Comment: Are you calling showNotify someplace?

Comment: What is the meaning of that body-less function on the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than likely this is running before all the elements with class NotifyBar are rendered

```
var getNotifyBar = $(".NotifyBar");
```

Which means that it is empty when you try to use it later. you should do this instead:

```
var getNotifyBar;
$(function ($) {
 getNotifyBar = $(".NotifyBar");
});
```

Now it should be properly loaded. Next, you need to remember that getNotifyBar is a reference to a jQuery object already loaded from a selector. As such, you do not need to wrap it in `$()`. You should make this change:

```
function showNotify(text) {
 getNotifyBar.hide().find(".text").html(text).end().slideDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no chance of working now and works from console, because when you run it in console it's after the DOMReady. Put the code in place of your 3 dots in the example and it will work, because:

```
$(function($){

//code here

})
```

will run the code after DOMReady